# Tensorflow ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Machine Learning, thought I'll start with keras. Here I'm classifying movie reviews as three class classification (positive as 1, neutral as 0 and negative as -1) using binary crossentropy. So, when I'm trying to wrap my keras model with tensorflow estimator, I get the error.
The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy as K

csvfilename_train = 'train(cleaned).csv'
csvfilename_test = 'test(cleaned).csv'

# Read .csv files as pandas dataframes
df_train = pd.read_csv(csvfilename_train)
df_test = pd.read_csv(csvfilename_test)

train_sentences  = df_train['Comment'].values
test_sentences  = df_test['Comment'].values

# Extract labels from dataframes
train_labels = df_train['Sentiment'].values
test_labels = df_test['Sentiment'].values

vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 30
trunc_type = 'post'
oov_tok = '<OOV>'

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token = oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_sentences)
padded = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen = max_length, truncating = trunc_type)

test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_sentences)
test_padded = pad_sequences(test_sequences, maxlen = max_length)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length = max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

num_epochs = 10
model.fit(padded, train_labels, epochs = num_epochs, validation_data = (test_padded, test_labels))
```

And the error is as follows:

```
---> 10 model.fit(padded, train_labels, epochs = num_epochs, validation_data = (test_padded, test_labels))
```

And finally this:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

Comment: One-hot encode your labels

Comment: @Rahul Vishwakarma My labels by default is -1, 0, 1. Do I still have to do one-hot encoding? As i said I am new to ML, please give a little more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You are using the wrong loss function. The binary cross-entropy loss is used for **binary classification** problems but here you are doing a multi-class classification (3 classes - positive, negative, neutral).
2. Using the sigmoid activation function in the last layer is wrong because the sigmoid function maps logit values to a range between 0 and 1 (However, your class labels are **0, 1 and -1**). This clearly shows that the network will never be able to predict a negative value because of the sigmoid function (which can only map values between 0 and 1) and hence, will never learn to predict the negative class.

The right approach would be to view this as a **multi-class classification problem** and use the **categorical cross-entropy loss** accompanied by the **softmax activation** in your last Dense layer with **3 units** (one for each class). Note that one-hot encoded labels have to be used for the [categorical cross-entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) loss and integer labels can be used along with the [sparse categorical cross-entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) loss.

Below is an example using categorical cross-entropy loss.

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')
```

Note the 3 changes:

- loss function changed to categorical cross-entropy
- No. of units in final Dense layer is 3
- One-hot encoding of labels is required and can be done using tf.one_hot

  tf.one_hot(train_labels, 3)

.

Comment: The sigmoid function could be used for a MultLabel-Multiclass problem though