# why is keras saying i only have one label instead of three

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

iam getting an error were tensorflow/keras is saying i only have one output so i should have a (1) in the dense layer instead of (4), i made an array of labels

```
#goes through files and turns images into arrays
#going through each folder
for categories in os.listdir('train'):
    category = str('train/' + folder)
    #going through each file in folder
    for files in os.listdir(category):
        #creates file path
        filePath = category + '/' + files
        image = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(filePath)
        imageArr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
        features.append(imageArr)

# makes labels
# iterates over folders
for names in os.listdir('train'):
      label = 0
      #increment as value of current folder
      label += 1
      for files in os.listdir('train/' + names):
          #adds a number per label
          labels.append(label)

features = np.asarray(features)
labels = np.asarray(labels)


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(30, (20, 20), input_shape=(600, 600, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the error iam getting states that i only have one output when i know i have 4 since when i print "labels" i get a siries of numbers going from 1-4 is it because it is all in one array? thanks for the help

error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 4) vs (None, 1))
```

Comment: How many classes do you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375201/tensorflow-valueerror-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-shape-none-2-vs)

Answer (score 0):

you have labels in the RANGE of 1 to 4 but you have 1 label per image. You specify your loss as binary_cross entropy. This means you should have 1 neuron in your dense layer not 4. Also your labels are in the range 1-4, they should be in the range 0-3 so in your code
for the labels should be

```
for names in os.listdir('train'):
      label = 0
      #increment as value of current folder      
      for files in os.listdir('train/' + names):
          #adds a number per label
          labels.append(label)
      label += 1
```